# Play! Framework Compilation Error - not found: value id

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using URI routing in Play! for the first time. That's what I have:

- Eclipse IDE, well updated IMHO;
- Error:

  ```
  Compilation error - not found: value id
  In C:\play\play-2.2.1\samples\java\forms\app\views\contact\form.scala.html at line 7.


  @import helper.twitterBootstrap._

  @title = {
    Add a new contact <small><a href="@routes.Contacts.edit(id: Long)">Or edit an existing contact</a></small> 
  }

  @phoneField(field: Field, className: String = "phone") = {
    @input(field, '_label -> "Phone numbers", '_class -> className) { (id, name, value, _) =>
    ...
  ```
- Routes:

  ```
  GET     /contacts/:id               controllers.Contacts.edit(id: Long)
  ```
- Controller:

  ```
  public static Result edit(Long id) {
      Contact existingContact = Contact.find.byId(3L);
      return ok(form.render(contactForm.fill(existingContact)));
  }
  ```

Well, that's it! What else could I check? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you refer to the `routes.Contacts.edit` route, you need to pass an id.  Right now, it looks like you just copied the parameter declaration (eg `id: Long`) instead of choosing a meaningful id to pass.

Declare your `title` block to accept the `id` as a parameter, eg:

```
@title(id: Long) = {
  Add a new contact <small><a href="@routes.Contacts.edit(id)">Or edit an existing contact</a></small> 
}
```

Then when you use it, pass the id, eg:

```
@title(someId)
```